# Combine CSV Files with MapReduce Function

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need help with mapreduce function in java. I have two input files:

file1.csv in this format:

```
Lat       Lon        Train delay
5.897888, 36.565678, 9
```

file2.csv in this format:

```
Lat      Lon       Temperature
9.7818,  19.2345,  2
```

Example of output

```
Lat      Lon       Temperature  Lat       Lon        Train delay
9.7818,  19.2345,  2,           5.897888, 36.565678, 9
```

How to get one output file from two input files?
Can someone help with this problem?

Comment: @m00am i have two map function and one reduce function           map1(LongWritable key, Text text, Context context1)

Comment: I would use Hive or Pig over MapReduce. Writing joins in plain MapReduce is not a simple task.

Comment: do you need the cross product of all elements? otherwise, what is the join criterion? do you need one SINGLE file as output?